# Windows can't repair even with sfc /scannow

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

I did a clean install of Windows 8, then installed the Windows 8.1 update (after all other updates).

[image]

CBS Log:
[CBS Log on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByGDeV45L_7LUlZSSXJZYTZjd00/edit?usp=sharing)

Important pieces of the log:

```
Found: {l:32 b:LrOXAtJDCCTN+z+D1bKj7ogYIrX7sfCCDh+wVBfsrCQ=} Expected: {l:32 b:n520k714Uu3utHa5JGQ6HQYbZphKhlMWq5pEmfnCDuw=}
2014-05-17 21:35:38, Info                  CSI    00000505 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" of prncacla.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-05-17 21:35:40, Info                  CSI    00000506 Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_prncacla.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_9590ba64d5b91f79\Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB do not match actual file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" :
  Found: {l:32 b:LrOXAtJDCCTN+z+D1bKj7ogYIrX7sfCCDh+wVBfsrCQ=} Expected: {l:32 b:n520k714Uu3utHa5JGQ6HQYbZphKhlMWq5pEmfnCDuw=}
2014-05-17 21:35:40, Info                  CSI    00000507 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" of prncacla.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-05-17 21:35:40, Info                  CSI    00000508 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:186{93}]"Microsoft-Windows-Printer-Drivers-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_prncacla"
2014-05-17 21:35:43, Info                  CSI    00000509 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [ml:520{260},l:138{69}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\NetSecurity\en" is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Networking-MPSSVC-WMI.Resources, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture = [l:10{5}]"en-US", VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral
```

And:

```
Found: {l:32 b:LrOXAtJDCCTN+z+D1bKj7ogYIrX7sfCCDh+wVBfsrCQ=} Expected: {l:32 b:n520k714Uu3utHa5JGQ6HQYbZphKhlMWq5pEmfnCDuw=}
2014-05-17 21:42:12, Info                  CSI    00000888 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" of prncacla.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-05-17 21:42:13, Info                  CSI    00000889 Hashes for file member \SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_prncacla.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_9590ba64d5b91f79\Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB do not match actual file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" :
  Found: {l:32 b:LrOXAtJDCCTN+z+D1bKj7ogYIrX7sfCCDh+wVBfsrCQ=} Expected: {l:32 b:n520k714Uu3utHa5JGQ6HQYbZphKhlMWq5pEmfnCDuw=}
2014-05-17 21:42:13, Info                  CSI    0000088a [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" of prncacla.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-05-17 21:42:13, Info                  CSI    0000088b [SR] This component was referenced by [l:186{93}]"Microsoft-Windows-Printer-Drivers-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_prncacla"
2014-05-17 21:42:13, Info                  CSI    0000088c [SR] Repair complete
```

Comment: btw, Microsoft is now investigating why this file gets corrupted so often. They also found the issue internally on their systems.

Comment: @magicandre1981, So how is the investigation coming along?

Comment: @Pacerier They saw it internally on several systems, but never found the cause and stopped the investigation

Comment: @magicandre1981, So is the conclusion "due to hardware problems", or is the conclusion there's a **bug** somewhere in there but they didn't managed to find it?

Comment: @Pacerier there is a bug, but they have no idea where the bug is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by using a third party theme, after setting it back to default, it's fine.

Comment: no, the **CNBJ2530.DPB** is part of a printer driver and was a known issue in Windows 8.1 that the file corrupts itself.

Comment: Do you feel good saying that while thinking you're right? I never had a printer on that machine. Also problem went away after removing my third party theme and switching back to the default.

Comment: this printer file is part of Windows, no matter if you use a printer or not. I had the same issue and submitted it to Microsoft 2 years ago. They confirmed that the file gets corrupted randomly (also on devices inside Microsoft), but they never found a cause. For Windows 10 I haven't seen this

Answer (score 24):

In Windows 8.x [run this new DISM command](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) to repair corrupted files from a cmd.exe, started as admin:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

It can download the corrupted files if needed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44144/discussion-on-answer-by-magicandre1981-windows-cant-repair-even-with-sfc-scanno).