# Manually replacing corrupt Windows file

Tags: windows-8.1, backup, winsxs, sfc

The results of my recent SFC scan have returned bad:

```
Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log %WinDir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.
```

[This Microsoft Support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833) says the backup files are stored in `%WinDir%\System32\dllcache`. So I embarked on the adventure into hidden system files. Result? **dllcache does not exist!**

Digging deeper, I found [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/deleted-dllcache-folder-need-help-to/23401a79-6ab2-44ae-84df-d82b202b04d8), which says dllcache was replaced with `C:\Windows\winsxs\Backup` starting with Windows Vista. Navigating there, all I find is a jumble of files where none of them have the name of the file which I'm trying to replace.

**What I did find** was that there was a MANIFEST file with the exact same name as the parent folder of the corrupt file.

Any words on this?

---

**sfcdetails:** All files have "Verify complete" except for the following (which is repeated in the log 3 times with different times and CSI numbers):

```
2015-07-12 22:53:08, Info                  CSI    00000594 [SR]
Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" of prncacla.inf,
Version = 6.3.9600.17415, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture
neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35},
Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the
store, hash mismatch
```

Comment: Feel free to provide the relevant information from the log file that was generated.

Comment: Updated with log information from CBS.log.

Comment: I could find no mention whatever of "dllcache" in the MS article you link to; it only suggests obtaining a copy of the corrupt file from another Windows installation. I hardly think there would be a spare copy on your computer without the System File Checker knowing about it or being able to use it.

Comment: Step 2. "The sfc /scannow command will scan all protected system files, and replace corrupted files with a cached copy that is located in a compressed folder at %WinDir%\System32\dllcache. "

Comment: [next step to repair prncacla.inf](http://superuser.com/questions/755680/windows-cant-repair-even-with-sfc-scannow)

Comment: Trying out the DISM command the answer recommended.  Will report back if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ramhound for the reference:

[Windows cant repair even with sfc /scannow](https://superuser.com/questions/755680/windows-cant-repair-even-with-sfc-scannow)

After running `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` and restarting my computer, System Restore works again!