# System Restore error 0x81000203

Tags: windows-8.1, system-restore

I recently realized that my System Restore isn't working.  Whenever I open System Properties or "Create a restore point", it gives me an error message.

[image: error message when opening System Restore]

**What I've tried:**

- According to https://superuser.com/questions/774607/windows-8-system-restore-failing, disabling UAC can prevent Windows applications from working.  But checking my registry, `EnableLUA` is set to `1` (on).
- According to another Q&A site, running `rstrui.exe` opens the System Restore dialog. But in the dialog, it says I don't have any restore points and it directs me to the System Properties page.
- [This Microsoft community post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/system-restore-error-code-0x81000203/8d051ee4-1bd3-4ead-8d6e-7c1150bdaedc?auth=1) suggests editing the SR policy from `gpedit.exe`, and confirming that `Microsoft Software Shadow Copy Provider` and `Volume Shadow Copy` services were running.
- Running an SFC scan to replace corrupt files can fix certain features. [See my other question for details.](https://superuser.com/questions/940026/manually-replacing-corrupt-windows-file)

Comment: I assume you have tried to disable then enable the feature?  Based on your other question, your system is corrupt, you can try using the DISM and SFC tools to fix the corruption though.

Comment: How would I disable system restore?  I'm looking into DISM currently, but I'm awaiting input on the results of my SFC scan.

Comment: How you disable system restore points is well documented.