# How to restart Windows top-left and top-right corner navigation?

Tags: windows, windows-8-apps, hot-corner

"Corner navigation" has been working fine all along, but suddenly it stops working. Nothing happens when the mouse is pointed to the top-left nor the top-right.

"PC and devices → Corners and devices" correctly shows:

[image]

Have tried refreshing the settings by setting them to "Off" and then "On" again, but it still doesn't work.

I suspect the *process* or *service* equivalent might've crashed. How can we *restart* it?

---

<sup>• Tested on Win 8.1 ([6.3.9600 N/A Build 9600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ver_(command)#Version_list)).


• Haven't been touching any screen settings, so it's unlikely that the failure is due to the mouse failing to grasp the exact location.


• Restarting isn't an option.


• Haven't been changing the "Corner Navigation" setting nor any other user setting. Just messing with some Bluetooth stuff (PC and devices → Bluetooth) when I realized the corner navigation has suddenly stopped working.</sup>

Comment: Verify the integrity of the system image by running SFC and DISM

Comment: @Ramhound, Ok, [am currently](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kKUQT.png) running `sfc /verifyonly`. I'd think this'll take an hour. Btw, what are the pertinent files that needs to be checked? Are you referring to the command [`dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`](http://superuser.com/questions/755680/windows-cant-repair-even-with-sfc-scannow#comment1215755_755684)?

Comment: Using those tools will verify all the files that need to be checked.

Comment: @Ramhound. Hmm, while the `/verifyonly` scan was still running, somehow the problem was solved. I think I solved it by locking the user acc. Either that, or it's due to logging in to another user acc. In any case, this is the result: http://i.stack.imgur.com/73JJx.png. The logs can be found at https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/wNSIfcLyqhUBOtUq5hMWUC1x7R4rDTkEEPVkVRDhcvE?ref_=cd_ph_share_link_copy. Btw, why had you suggested to run `sfc`? How is the scan relevant to the question?

Comment: I suspected system corruption and those tools can fix it

Comment: @Ramhound, But would they re-run the processes that have crashed? (such that the corner navigation can start working again)

Comment: They don't the last step to fix the corruption is to actually restart the system, logging in and out of the user would have also refreshed those system files.

Comment: @Ramhound, Ic .