# Windows 10 unexpected store exception

Tags: windows-10, window, windows-error-reporting

I execute `sfc /scannow`
Windows resource find corrupted file. However, it can not restore it!

Here is
[CBS.Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kq2x9whvpmrgmyg/CBS.log?dl=0)

I keep getting **unexpected_store_exception**

*After apply suggested solution*
I still get this **unexpected store exception** error.

The problem still happening.

I tried

1. I uninstall Avast Anti-Virus
2. clean install with new Window 10 ISO USB installer
3. disabled "Fast Startup"
4. `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`
5. `sfc /scannow`

But, still does not solved error.

Here is my minidumps.
[Minidump.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i6vu8fekadd5h19/Desktop.zip?dl=0)

If you want more information or log, Just make a comment what you need (b.b)

Comment: Does the volume have any other errors?

Comment: use DISM....instead...or install Version 1607 update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows cant repair even with sfc /scannow](http://superuser.com/questions/755680/windows-cant-repair-even-with-sfc-scannow)

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks! I think it maybe fixed my problem.

Comment: Please let us know if it did, so that we can mark this question as a duplicate to point people in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry, the problem still happening..

Comment: Please explain what you mean by you performed a clean installation, if you did that, your corrupt installation would have been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug data are missing for but [while analyzing the dmp file with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) I see a memory corruption in `volmgrx.sys`:

```
255 errors : !volmgrx (fffff80130c31000-fffff80130c310ff)
fffff80130c31000 *f8 *f4 *f3 *ff *f7 *f2 *f1 *ff *f9 *f4 *f1 *ff *f5 *f3 *f2 *ff ................
fffff80130c31010 *f7 *f2 *f3 *ff *f8 *f4 *f3 *ff *f7 *f4 *f0 *ff *fb *f5 *f0 *ff ................
fffff80130c31020 *f6 *f4 *f4 *ff *fc *f6 *f1 *ff *f6 *f4 *f4 *ff *f8 *f4 *f3 *ff ................
fffff80130c31030 *f6 *f4 *f3 *ff *f6 *f4 *f4 *ff *f6 *f4 *f4 *ff *f6 *f4 *f4 *ff ................
fffff80130c31040 *f6 *f4 *f4 *ff *f6 *f4 *f4 *ff *f6 *f4 *f4 *ff *f6 *f4 *f4 *ff ................
fffff80130c31050 *f6 *f4 *f4 *ff *f8 *f3 *f5 *ff *f8 *f4 *f3 *ff *f9 *f4 *f3 *ff ................
fffff80130c31060 *f9 *f3 *f4 *ff *fa *f6 *f1 *ff *f6 *f4 *f3 *ff *f6 *f5 *f1 *ff ................
fffff80130c31070 *f8 *f3 *f4 *ff *f8 *f3 *f4 *ff *f7 *f5 *f4 *ff *f8 *f4 *f3  ff ................
fffff80130c31080 *fb *f6 *f3 *ff *f8 *f5 *f1 *ff *f8 *f4 *f3 *ff *f7 *f5 *f5 *ff ................
fffff80130c31090 *f6 *f4 *f3 *ff *f8 *f4 *f3 *ff *f9 *f4 *f5 *ff *f8 *f3 *f4 *ff ................
fffff80130c310a0 *f6 *f4 *f4 *ff *f8 *f5 *f1 *ff *f8 *f3 *f2 *ff *f8 *f3 *f4 *ff ................
fffff80130c310b0 *f8 *f4 *f3 *ff *f8 *f3 *f2 *ff *f6 *f5 *f1 *ff *f8 *f3 *f4 *ff ................
fffff80130c310c0 *f5 *f3 *f3 *ff *f7 *f4 *f0 *ff *f8 *f2 *f3 *ff *f7 *f3 *f2 *ff ................
fffff80130c310d0 *f8 *f5 *f0 *ff *f7 *f4 *f0 *ff *f7 *f2 *f3 *ff *f8 *f3 *f2 *ff ................
fffff80130c310e0 *f7 *f3 *f2 *ff *f4 *f2 *f1 *ff *f6 *f4 *f3 *ff *fa *f2 *f2 *ff ................
fffff80130c310f0 *f6 *f3 *ef *ff *f6 *f1 *f2 *ff *f4 *f1 *f3 *ff *f8 *ef *f2 *ff ................

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  memory_corruption

MEMORY_CORRUPTOR:  LARGE_256

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0xffffd00026201c30 ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE_256

BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE_256

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE_256
```

If DISM was succesfull to repair all files, the file may get corrupted in memory. So run [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) and check the `Samsung M378B1G73EB0-CK0` RAM module for errors.

Comment: Thanks to provide a solution! I will try it out and I will report it to you. (I will just wait for a couple of days to check whether solved or not.) And, if you do not mind, How did you find this problem? Or, Can you enlighten me how can I learn to check logs?

Comment: I added the link to a video on how to use Windbg to get BSOD data: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

Comment: Thanks! I figure it out that my hard drive was broken. I tested out my memory and did not found problem. And I look into windows log, the problem always happen when copy information from memory to hard drive. I had broken sectors.

Comment: ok, this is also a cause, so the file was corrupted on disk. Enjoy your stable PC now