# Windows 10 update KB3198586 has failed for about a week now, reverting changes at 99%

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I've noticed other people complain about this issue, but I haven't found any working fix for this.
I've tried some "[registry fix](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53942)" that was suggested in a few places.
I've tried manually installing the update.
I've tried automated Updater troubleshooting. (Which claims there's a problem, and claims it fixed it, but then it finds the problem again immediately.)

Is it perhaps likely that some future update won't fail, and it will then stop trying to install this one every single day?

Comment: share the log files from C:\windows\logs\cbs share the whole folder) and I'll look what is wrong

Comment: @magicandre1981 [Here should be the entire folder. It looks quite large though.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1X0IiDK7Q7sVm1uRDNvNDg5YWs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I posted what I see from the log. Also update to V1607 and install here the latest update rollup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the Edge Browser fails for you:

```
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Info                  CSI    00000416 Begin executing advanced installer phase 38 (0x00000026) index 387 (0x0000000000000183) (sequence 426)
    Old component: [l:163 ml:164]"Microsoft-Windows-MicrosoftEdge.appxsetup, Culture=neutral, Version=10.0.10586.0, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=amd64, versionScope=NonSxS"
    New component: [l:165 ml:166]"Microsoft-Windows-MicrosoftEdge.appxsetup, Culture=neutral, Version=10.0.10586.672, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=amd64, versionScope=NonSxS"
    Install mode: install
    Smart installer: FALSE
    Installer ID: {f1aab1ba-6ee0-4d94-baeb-c9fd61f365cf}
    Installer name: [27]"AppX Registration Installer"
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Info                  CSI    00000417 Performing 1 operations as follows:
  (0)  LockComponentPath: flags: 0 comp: {l:16 b:551c6b266b41d2013103000054047404} pathid: {l:16 b:551c6b266b41d2013203000054047404} path: [l:117]"\SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-m..osoftedge.appxsetup_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.0_none_2fd039de83dfcff2" pid: 454 starttime: 131239266743228970 (0x01d2416af2d01a2a)
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Info                  CSI    00000418 Performing 1 operations as follows:
  (0)  LockComponentPath: flags: 0 comp: {l:16 b:551c6b266b41d2013303000054047404} pathid: {l:16 b:551c6b266b41d2013403000054047404} path: [l:119]"\SystemRoot\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-m..osoftedge.appxsetup_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.672_none_1032f35338a83d85" pid: 454 starttime: 131239266743228970 (0x01d2416af2d01a2a)
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Info                  CSI    00000419@2016/11/18:07:12:40.902 Package Full Name found from manifest: [68]"Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_25.10586.672.0_neutral_neutral_8wekyb3d8bbwe"
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Info                  CSI    0000041a@2016/11/18:07:12:40.902 Enumerating Key [l:125 ml:126]"\Registry\Machine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\S-1-5-21-3113158878-279418048-46284876-1001".
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Info                  CSI    0000041b@2016/11/18:07:12:40.902 Enumerating Key [l:135 ml:136]"\Registry\Machine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\AppxAllUserStore\EndOfLife\S-1-5-21-3113158878-279418048-46284876-1001".
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Error                 CSI    0000041c@2016/11/18:07:12:40.902 (F) base\appmodel\inboxappinstallerai\appxreg.cpp(87): Error HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(1058) originated in function Windows::WCP::AppXRegistration::BasicInstaller::Install expression: RDSAppXOnlineNotifyPackageChanges(APPCHANGETYPE_INBOX)
[gle=0x80004005]
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log to WER report.
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20161118064047.log to WER report.
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20161118052620.log to WER report.
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20161118045519.log to WER report.
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20161117062632.log to WER report.
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Info                  CBS    Added C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20161116045212.log to WER report.
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Info                  CBS    Could not get active session for current session file logging [HRESULT = 0x80004003 - E_POINTER]
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml.bad to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-11-18 09:12:40, Info                  CBS    Not able to add SCM.EVM to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-11-18 09:12:41, Error      [0x018051] CSI    0000041d (F) Failed execution of queue item Installer: AppX Registration Installer ({f1aab1ba-6ee0-4d94-baeb-c9fd61f365cf}) with HRESULT HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(1058).  Failure will not be ignored: A rollback will be initiated after all the operations in the installer queue are completed; installer is reliable[gle=0x80004005]
2016-11-18 09:12:41, Info                  CSI    0000041e@2016/11/18:07:12:41.027 CSI Advanced installer perf trace:
CSIPERF:AIDONE;{f1aab1ba-6ee0-4d94-baeb-c9fd61f365cf};Microsoft-Windows-MicrosoftEdge.appxsetup, version 10.0.10586.672, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35};131096us
2016-11-18 09:12:41, Info                  CSI    0000041f End executing advanced installer (sequence 426)
    Completion status: HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_ADVANCED_INSTALLER_FAILED)
```

This can happen when App Readiness service is disabled.

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't actually think this could be solved that easily. If I had this problem in the future, is it... easy enough to diagnose it myself?

Comment: look for this line in the log **Failure will not be ignored: A rollback will be initiated after all the operations in the installer queue are completed** Now look for the 20 line before which operation(s) fail and cause the rollback. Here I see that RDSAppXOnlineNotifyPackageChanges(APPCHANGETYPE_INBOX) fails, doing a google search points to this site: http://www.eightforums.com/windows-updates-activation/46273-may-13-updates-will-not-install-2.html and here a app readiness service solution was shown as cause.

Comment: I was perhaps a little bit hasty in assuming all my issues had been fixed. While this did fix the main problem of my computer taking 15 minutes to start up due to the required rollback, it seems the update is still failing. Seems it doesn't even begin to install it, as no percentages are shown. As there's no rollback there is also no such line in the log. If you're feeling generous, you can try helping me again [(new logs)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1X0IiDK7Q7sTGktNWtBb0FiT1k), but I suppose that's not within the scope of this question. In any case, you've been a great help, thank you.

Comment: this time you have **STATUS_TRANSACTIONAL_CONFLICT** error. Try DISM to repair this: http://superuser.com/a/755684/174557