# Windows 10 latest insider builds crashes when save file or browse file

Tags: windows-10, windows-insider, windows-10-v1703

In recent insider builds, lots of desktop apps crashes upon saving a file or browse for a file. The error is something as below

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA166E134D (shell32.dll) in Xamarin Workbooks.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF8B.
```

Now I am using the Build 15063.14 with latest updates. This is really really frustrating as I cannot attach a file as attachment in outlook.com with Google Chrome or save a workbook in Xamarin Workbooks.

This error happens on both my machines which both run insider builds

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Xamarin. Have you tried uninstalling it?

Comment: the tool accesses a NULL pointer. this is a bug in tools. report it to developers.

Comment: No, it's not an issue with Xamarin since Chrome had the same issue - crash when browse file / save file, other apps too. I am pretty sure it's a bug in the system level.

Comment: create crash dumps of Windows inbox tools (notepad.exe) if it has the same issue and share the dmp: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638(VS.85).aspx. Set **DumpType** to 2 to get a full dmp

Comment: Yup, notepad.exe has the same issue

Comment: @magicandre1981 I collected the dump, what else?

Comment: zip the dmp, upload the zip to OneDrive, create a share link and post the share link here. I'll look at the dump and also ask my Microsoft contacts for help.

Comment: @magicandre1981, the link is https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au3MY0PcVMtTjt4XyF0ocQnpAa5q7w
thanks

Comment: yesterday there was an update to 15063.138. do you see the crashes here, too? also generate a FULL dump, not a minidump. create a DWORD DumpType and set this to 2.

Comment: I did as told, this is the link of the dump file
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au3MY0PcVMtTjt4YyK0V5Qs1rG3OOQ

Comment: the dump shows a memory corruption for shell32.dll. use first chkdsk to look if your NTFS is damaged, next run [DISM](https://superuser.com/a/755684/174557) to look for damaged system files. Have you installed the last update to update to 15063.138?

Comment: do you also see the crash if you disable Bins ( C:\Program Files\1UPIndustries\Bins\v1.1.0.784\TaskbarDockAppIntegration64.dll)?

Comment: It cannot be with disk damage because I had this issue with both my machines. It could be Bins though. I'll see whether it is Bins that is causing this issue

Comment: Indeed it was Bins that is causing this issue. I'll uninstall it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it is the `Bins` program that's causing these crashes. Thanks for @magicandre1981's help!

Comment: ok, nice to see that it is now fixed. report it to the support of Bins

Comment: ok, they [wrote on twitter](https://twitter.com/1UPIndustries/status/855868269361639424) that an update is coming the next weeks.

Comment: Good to know that they are working on the fix

Comment: This should be a comment.Or provide a more detailed answer