# File Open/Save Dialog causing applications to crash

Tags: windows-10, crash

Seemingly ever since the Windows 10 Creators Update installed itself on my computer, I've been having issues when using the File Open/Save dialog. If I try and open a file, save a file, or upload a file to attach to an email, the application that I'm using will crash (whether it's Chrome, Word, Paint etc). Edge, however, works fine and weirdly, Firefox also works fine.

I have been doing some debugging, trying to figure out what it could be, but I'm running out of things to try.

I've tried the following:

- Resetting folder views to default
- Enabling "Show all Folders" in Folder View Settings
- Starting computer in safe mode (where the dialog would work just fine)

I have also run some tests using MS Paint. I downloaded an application called DebugDiag 2, and had that watch the mspaint process to capture the exceptions thrown when the application would crash. These are the ID's of those exceptions:

- 0XC000001D
- 0XC000041D

Still using MS Paint as my test application, if I ran it as an adminstrator, I was able to use the File Open/Save dialog perfectly fine, but closing the application then reopening as a normal user would then end with the application crashing upon trying to open a file.

Another thing I've noticed is that when I first sign into Windows, I have about 30 seconds where I can open MS Paint, and be able to use the File Open/Save dialog just fine. After that time, if I close the dialog and then try to use it again, the application will crash.

I've read online that this issue is sometimes caused by the File Open/Save dialog trying to show a folder that no longer exists, or is on an unreachable network drive. So with that in mind, I have restarted my computer (getting that 30 seconds of grace when I first sign in) to be able to open MS Paint, and save a new file to my downloads folder, in the hopes that it would update the "last used folder". Unfortunately, this didn't solve the issue.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: check [this topic](https://superuser.com/q/1196081/174557) and look if you have Bins insalled

Comment: Unbeliebable, how did anyone figure out that was the issue! Thanks for pointing out the topic to me, it's fixed my problem!